# Pegar dois valores no arduino e exibir no C#

Tags: c#, arduino

Tenho dois Ultrassônicos ligados no meu arduino, e estou usando este código para ler os valores deles normalmente:

```
#include <Ultrasonic.h>

Ultrasonic ultrasonic(11, 12);
Ultrasonic ultrasonic1(8,9);  

const int TRIG = 8;
const int ECHO = 9;

const int TRIG2 = 11;
const int ECHO2 =12;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode (TRIG,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (ECHO,INPUT);

  pinMode (TRIG2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (ECHO2,INPUT);

}


void loop() {

 int data = GetUltra(TRIG,ECHO);
 int data2 = GetUltra(TRIG2,ECHO2);
 char recep = data+"_"+data2;
 Serial.println(recep);
delay(200);

}

double GetUltra(int trig, int echo){

   digitalWrite (trig,LOW);
   delayMicroseconds(2);
   digitalWrite (trig,HIGH);
   delayMicroseconds(8);
   digitalWrite (trig,LOW);

       double distance = (pulseIn(echo, HIGH) )*343.2 / 20000;
       return distance;

}
```

E agora, estou tentando ler os valores no meu sisteminha no visual Studio, usando Split. Porém, o retorna o valor de somente 1 numero

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    message = porta.ReadLine();
    Receptor = message.ToString().Split('_');
    MessageBox.Show("message2" + Receptor[0]);
    MessageBox.Show("message2" + Receptor[1]);

}
```

Fiz algo de errado? Não estou seguindo o pensamento certo?

Comment: Qual o valor de `message` recebido no C#?

Comment: Bem me retornava um valor bem esquisito com caracteres e numero(ex: @#sadv4355345@@#$%@),estou desconfiando de um curto que esteja chegando no Arduíno,vou pegar alguns equipamentos e refazer o teste

Comment: Está correto seu código. Já verificou se no monitor serial dado é mostrado corretamente?

Comment: @IuryPereira se está chegando os caracteres de forma **estranha**, isto indica que a velocidade da porta serial configurada no Arduino é diferente do configurado no C#. Outro detalhe importante, a mensagem pode não estar completa, por isto recomento ter um finalizador de mensagem. Se precisar te passo um código meu de comunicação do Arduino com C# e porta serial.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema esteja aqui nesta linha:

```
char recep = data+"_"+data2;
```

Você está usando o tipo "char" quando na verdade deveria usar o tipo "string".